# How to process logs from distributed log broker (Eg Kafka) exactly after 1 week?

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-storm

What can be the setup if I want to process the logs which are exactly 1 week old from Kafka?

Usecase is that I maintain cumulative stats of the last 1 week's user activity. I am fine with eventual consistency and don't need the stats to be for exactly 1 week.

I have a streaming setup which processes the incoming logs from Kafka and updates the stats. Any activity older than 1 week should be deleted from the stats. One of the ways I can achieve is using a batch process (eg Spark) to remove activity older than 1 week from the stats.

Is there any way I can use stream processing to remove user activity older than 1 week from stats? What are the pros and cons of various approaches?

if I use at least once in Kafka and stats deviate from the ground truth, what are the ways to correct the stats regularly?

Comment: You can `watermarking` concept from Spark structured streaming!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Kafka messages have a proper timestamp, then you can get the offsets for the timestamp of the previous week. So you can use..

```
Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndTimestamp> offsetsForTimes(Map<TopicPartition,Long> timestampsToSearch)
```

The [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#offsetsForTimes-java.util.Map-) says:

> Look up the offsets for the given partitions by timestamp. The
> returned offset for each partition is the earliest offset whose
> timestamp is greater than or equal to the given timestamp in the
> corresponding partition.

For getting the list of topic partitions, you can call `consumer.assignment()` (after `subscribe()` or `assign()`) which returns `Set<TopicPartition>` assigned to the consumer. The `Long` value in the map is basically, the timestamp. So, for all keys in your case, it will be the same value (i.e. 1 week old timestamp)

Now, that you have got a `Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp>`. You can now use `seek(TopicPartition partition, long offset)` to seek to each offset.

```
consumer.subscribe(topics);
Set<TopicPartition> partitions = consumer.assignment();
Map<TopicPartition, Long> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
partitions.forEach(partition -> map.put(partition, oneWeekOldTimestamp));
Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndTimestamp> offsetsMap = consumer.offsetForTimes(map);
offsetsMap.forEach((partition, offsetTimestamp) -> consumer.seek(partition, offsetTimestamp.offset()));
```

Now, your consumer will be at position of messages that have been one week old. So, when you `poll()`, you poll from last week till now.

You can change your timestamp to meet your requirements, for example, anything older than 1 week means, from timestamp 0 to last week timestamp.

All previous week data means, `2weekOldTimestamp - 1weekOldTimestamp`.

So, in this case you have to seek to `2weekOldTimestamp` and then process each partition till you encounter `1weekOldTimestamp`